# When running two for loops at once to create an Isogram, Why does this algorithm require me to make j = i +1?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

An isogram is a word that has no repeating letters, consecutive or non-consecutive. 
Why do I need to set j = i +1?

```
var git = "pot-luck"

function isIsogram(str){
  var i; var j
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  for(**i = 0**; i < str.length; ++i){
    for(**j = i+1** ; j < str.length; ++j){
      if(str[i] === str[j])
        return false;}
  }
  return true;
}

isIsogram(git)
```

Comment: Because you have already checked the prior letters.  You only need to be sure that a single letter doesn't repeat.

Comment: Im totally lost, can you please go into more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay let us take a couple of simple examples NOMIM and ABCDEFG

These would be the arrays with their indexes:

```
0 - N
1 - O
2 - M
3 - I
4 - M
```

and:

```
0 - A
1 - B
2 - C
3 - D
4 - E
5 - F
6 - G
```

The first example has the M that repeats.
So lets go through the loop.

So `i = 0` and then `j` loops from `1 to 4`

```
Comparing `N to O` - No Match
Comparing `N to M` - No Match
Comparing `N to I` - No Match
Comparing `N to M` - No Match
```

So now we go to `i = 1` and `j` loops from `2 to 4` since we know that the first character didn't repeat.

```
Comparing `O to M` - No Match
Comparing `O to I` - No Match
Comparing `O to M` - No Match
```

We know now that O didn't repeat. We continue to test `i = 2` and `j` from `3 to 4`

```
Comparing `M to I` - No Match
Comparing `M to M` - Match.  Exit because a letter repeated.
```

The second example we would loop the same way. Verifying one by one.  Once we are sure a letter hasn't repeated we don't have to recheck the previously verified letters.  Which is why we loop `j` for each letter after `i`

Comment: And to add to that. They would all be false if i and j started at the same index because you would compare the same numbers against each other.

Comment: That is true.  Definitely would defeat the purpose of the check.

Answer (score 0):

When you start looping you begin at `index 0`, with `i`. In this case you are checking 'g' in your example.

You then loop through with `j` but you do not need to to check 'g' again, so you add one to `i`, and start at the next index, which is the letter 'i'. And so on until you finish looping through the string.